# How to return all elements from an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, decorator

There is a page where you can see the details of a user's loan. There is a decorator where I return values ​​using the get () method. In general, there is a partial refund, which returns items of partial payments as shown in the photo. My problem is that I cannot specify all partial payments, only receive one by one.

Loan Details component:

```
 <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content__inner__wrapper">
                    {Object.keys(payments[0]).map(val => {
                      {
                        [payments[0][val]].map((payment: any, index: number) => (
                          <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-inner" key={index}>
                            {paymentsFields.map((item, indexInner) => (
                              <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item" key={indexInner}>
                                <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item__title">
                                  {item.title}
                                </div>
                                <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item__value">
                                  {payment[item.key]}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            ))}
                          </div>
                        ));
                      }}
                    )
                    }}
                  </div>
```

This is code snippet for key & titles from loan.ts:

```
export const repaymentsFields = [
  {
    key: 'issuedDate',
    title: lang.CLIENTS.REPAYMENTS.ISSUED_DATE,
  },
  {
    key: 'period',
    title: lang.CLIENTS.REPAYMENTS.PERIOD_IN_DAYS,
  },
]
```

JSON of repayments:

```
"partialRepayments": [
                    {
                        "orderId": "A11Fz090VT1BmObJ0S-0",
                        "repaidPrincipalAmount": {
                            "amount": 250000.0
                        },
                        "repaidInterestAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "repaidOverdueAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "repaidProlongationAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "started": "2020-11-09T16:52:08.981+0600",
                        "completed": "2020-11-09T16:52:21.170+0600",
                        "period": 25,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-09T16:52:21.174+0600"
                    },
                    {
                        "orderId": "A11Fz090VT1BmObJ0S-1",
                        "repaidPrincipalAmount": {
                            "amount": 300000.0
                        },
                        "repaidInterestAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "repaidOverdueAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "repaidProlongationAmount": {
                            "amount": 0
                        },
                        "started": "2020-11-09T16:54:31.923+0600",
                        "completed": "2020-11-09T16:54:46.313+0600",
                        "period": 25,
                        "timestamp": "2020-11-09T16:54:46.317+0600"
                    }
                ],
```

the problem is that it is impossible to display the values ​​that come as in the photo (one loan may have several repayments)
I have to return all values from an Object
[IMAGE of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQS1R.png)

Comment: Please describe your issue not in terms of business logic, but in terms of logic :)

Comment: :D the issues is that when I try to use map to return all payments it doesn't work(f.e. if instead of payments[0][val] I put payments[0][0] first payments will be showed. I need to display all payments which comes from loan details

Comment: can u show json example of the source arrays/objects? like how does payments array look like.

Comment: this taken from console.log(): example of loan with 2 payments: `0:
completed: "09/11/2020"
orderId: "A11Fz090VT1BmObJ0S-0"
period: 25
repaidInterestAmount: 0
repaidOverdueAmount: 0
repaidPrincipalAmount: 250000
repaidProlongationAmount: 0
started: "09/11/2020"
timestamp: "09/11/2020"
__proto__: Object
1:
completed: "09/11/2020"
orderId: "A11Fz090VT1BmObJ0S-1"
period: 25
repaidInterestAmount: 0
repaidOverdueAmount: 0
repaidPrincipalAmount: 300000
repaidProlongationAmount: 0
started: "09/11/2020"
timestamp: "09/11/2020"`

Comment: also there is link to the photo in the post

Comment: I've updated post and added info with json

Comment: can't you just iteratre over payments?
You know you can just put your tags (e.g. divs) into the function and do some work there?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop through the `partialPayementResponse` and access each field through the dot . notation ? Such as follows:

```
<div>
  {partialRepayments.map((item, index) => {
    return (
    <div key={index}>
      <div>Completed: <span>{item.completed}</span></div>
      <div>orderId: <span>{item.orderId}</span></div>
      <div>period: <span>{item.orderId}</span></div>
      <div>repaidInterestAmount: <span>{item.repaidInterestAmount.amount}</span></div>
      <div>repaidOverdueAmount: <span>{item.repaidOverdueAmount.amount}</span></div>
      <div>repaidPrincipalAmount: <span>{item.repaidPrincipalAmount.amount}</span></div>
      <div>repaidProlongationAmount: <span>{item.repaidProlongationAmount.amount}</span></div>
      <div>started: <span>{item.started}</span></div>
      <div>timestamp: <span>{item.timestamp}</span></div>
    </div>)
  })}
</div>
```

I wrote it without using your `className`s but I think you get the idea

Comment: actually, my problem is not about accessing through dot notation. I decorated retrieved data in another ts class & it retrieved correctly. my problem is not correct looping => I can not display all payments

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the problem here.
Can't u just iterate over these things?

Or create function and then display the thing that function returns...

for example:

```
displayAppropriateFields = () => {
    let returnedArray = [];
    
    returnedArray.push(<div> Some text in the div </div>);

    for(let i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
        returnedArray.push(<span> someArray[i] </span>)
    }
    
    return returnedArray;
}
```

And then display it in render method like so:

```
this.displayAppropriateFields();
```